# How to use do end block on a instance(object itself) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-gnome2

```
w = Gtk::window.new
w do
   title = "foo"
   resizable = false
   foo = bar
end
```

I want to call every method in the block to `self` after passing it to the block.

-thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe one way to do that could be usage of [#instance_eval](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_eval) like:

```
a = 'asd'
a.instance_eval do
  a.upcase!
end

a # => ASD
```

Other way to get an object inside a block is by using [#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-tap), but you will not have self:

```
gkt_window = Gtk::window.new

gtk_window.tap do |w|
  w.title     = 'foo'
  w.resizable = false
  w.foo       = bar
end # Now gtk_window will have all properties set and you can chain methods to this block
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BasicObject#instance_eval`:

```
w.instance_eval do
  title = 'foo'
  resizable = false
  foo = bar
end
```